# ActiveRecord outputs too much in select query for Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, select, activerecord, web-applications

According to:

```
@actors = actors.to_sql
```

this query:

```
actors = Actor.select("actors.name")
```

supposed to be equal to:

```
SELECT actors.name FROM `actors`
```

And it works in my SQL; only selects actors.name ... so i try:

```
@actors = actors.to_json.to_s
```

and render on some view... I get this;

```
[{"name":"James Patrick Pe","id":null,"logo":{"url":"uploads/default.jpg","topbar_avatar":{"url":"uploads/topbar_avatar_default.jpg"}}},{"name":"SSS","id":null,"logo":{"url":"uploads/default.jpg","topbar_avatar":{"url":"uploads/topbar_avatar_default.jpg"}}},{"name":"Philhealth","id":nul ....
```

it's basically a JSON of everything... I only need one column for an AJAX reply. How can I do this with the ActiveRecord Way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Paperclip? It's likely you have a method that appends something to your JSON.

What you need to do is to specify the fields you want to be exported.

```
@actors = actors.to_json(only: [:name]).to_s
```

Also please note that there is a better approach to `to_json`. You should definitely have serializers that take an object or collection in input and deal with the serialization.